# Tomcat can't find class that is placed directly under classes folder

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following JSP:

```html
<%@ page import="foo.*" %>
<html>
    <body>
        The page count is:
        <%=Counter.getCount()%>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have a `Counter` class in package `foo` which is stored in:

> C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\webapps\God\WEB-INF\classes

And the container could find the class from its package `foo`.

But when I try to add some other class file directly under `\WEB-INF\classes` and not in any specific package such as `foo`, then container can't find that class.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: did you specify your other class in 'import' instruction?

Comment: two no-nos: a) don't ever use the default package, b) don't use java code in JSPs

Comment: You have by the way a HTML syntax error in your JSP.

Comment: @AVD Sir, I restarted tomcat but it did no help

Comment: @ Sean Patrick Floyd, BalusC Sir, when I used this code, it worked for foo package

Comment: @user961690 Have you read BalusC (Below) answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classes in the default package are not visible to classes which are by itself inside a package. You **must** put the class in a package whenever you want to import it in another class which is by itself inside a package. Technically, when JSP files are compiled, the container will autogenerate a `.class` file which is by itself inside a package. So you cannot import classes from the default package in the JSP.

So, whenever you want to be able to reuse a class anywhere, it has to be placed in a concrete package, not in the default package. As an exercise, create two classes yourself, one which is inside a package and other which is not inside a package. Now, inside the one with package, try to `import` and use the one without package. You'll see that it's not possible and the code won't compile. The servletcontainer encounters exactly the same problem "under the hoods".

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorial - Lesson: Packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: writing raw Java code in JSP files is a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Consider learning and using [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Thank You very much SIR! Have a lovely day!